# Frobenius theorem on complex manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

On real differential manifolds, the Frobenius theorem says that any involutive distribution is integrable.

I'm wondering if the theorem generalize to complex manifolds?

My concern is with integral curves, on real manifolds we can define integral curves to vector fields, but how do we do this on complex manifolds? In proving the real case, we need to use flows of vector fields; is this still true on complex manifolds? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: By "Is this still true...", are you asking about finding real integral curves, or some type of complex curves induced by a vector field on a holomorphic manifold? (The Frobenius theorem holds on a holomorphic manifold viewed as a real manifold, of course, so whatever the interpretation of your question, the answer presumably comes down to the real Frobenius theorem.)

Comment: I meant is it still true that if we have an involutive distribution (closed under lie brackets), there exist complex integral manifolds of that distribution?

Comment: Is the distribution a holomorphic subbundle of the holomorphic tangent bundle?

Comment: yes! a holomorphic subbundle.

Answer (score 2):

See Nirenberg's [*A Complex Frobenius Theorem*](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL20424302M/A_complex_Frobenius_theorem.).